# Get only a specified name of email

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, php-5.3

I have a problem with preg_math. So I have this methode :

```
public function filterUsers($a_users){

    $a_authorizedEmail = array(
        '@test.com',
        '@test1.com'
    );

    $a_response = array();
    foreach ($a_users as $user) {
        if(false !== $email_user = EmailRepository::getEmail($user['id'])){
            foreach($a_authorizedEmail as $email){
                echo $email_user;
                if(preg_match($email, $email_user)){
                    $a_response[]= $user;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $a_response;
}
```

The array with `$a_users` : I have a user with email `hcost@test.com`. But in the return the array is empty. Probably I doen't made a correct verification. Please help me

Comment: You could benefit from a regex tutorial. [this one](https://regexone.com/references/php) looks decent.

Comment: not sure about you want. but it seems that you need to use `str_pos` or `explode` to get the email host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
public function filterUsers($a_users){

    $a_authorizedEmail = array(
        '@test.com',
        '@test1.com'
    );
    $pattern = "/".implode("|",$a_authorizedEmail)."$/"; //Note the "/" start and end delimiter as well as the $ that indicates end of line
    $a_response = array();
    foreach ($a_users as $user) {
        $email_user = EmailRepository::getEmail($user['id']);  
        if(false !== $email_user){ 
            echo $email_user;
            if(preg_match($pattern, $email_user)){
                $a_response[]= $user;
            }
        }
    }
    return $a_response;
}
```